# Screen orientation/Auto rotation on only one screen in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, screen, screen-orientation

I want to apply screen orientation on only one of the screens in my application. I have tried to apply it using if condition and orientation builder but somehow, it is not working.
For Example, If a user presses the auto-rotation button, the screen should behave according to the rotation but I want it only on one screen.

//main.dart

```
           void main(
           {
           WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();        
           SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations
           ([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
            runApp(IframeScreen());
            }






                  import 'dart:async';
                  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
                  import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
                  import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
                  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
                  import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart';
                  import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

                 class IframeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
                  @override
                 _IframeScreenState createState() => _IframeScreenState();
                  }

                 class _IframeScreenState extends State<IframeScreen> {

                  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

                  IframeScreen iframe = new IframeScreen();

                  _IframeScreenState(
  
                   @override
                   void initState() {
                   onLoadingTesting().then((value) {
                   print('check modalprogress');


                 });

             super.initState();
        }
          @override
          void dispose(){
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp
         ]);
         super.dispose();
         }

            InAppWebView webViewMethod() {
            WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
            Permission.camera.request();
            Permission.microphone.request();
           }
          }

           @override
           Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return ModalProgressHUD(
  inAsyncCall: _saving,
  child: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: (){
      if(MediaQuery.of(context).orientation==Orientation.landscape){
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
      }

      return Future.value(true);
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      body:  OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context,orientation) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                      initialUrl:
                      "https://appr.tc/r/158489234",
                      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                          debuggingEnabled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onWebViewCreated: (
                          InAppWebViewController controller) {
                        _webViewController = controller;
                      },
                      androidOnPermissionRequest:
                          (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin,
                          List<String> resources) async {
                        return PermissionRequestResponse(
                            resources: resources,
                            action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                      }),
                ),
              )
            ],

          );
        }
      )

    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you should set a preferred orientation in you main() method as

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
```

This will ensure that your app will be on portrait (as set in this sample code), until you change it.

A suggestion here is, in the screen which you need to be landscape, rather than changing the orientation inside the Dispose function, wrap the scaffold with a "WillPopScope", and implement the OnWillPop() method as follows

```
onWillPop: () {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  },
```

This will give a smoother transition from the landscape screen to the portrait screen.

Cheers!

Comment: @utkarsh yes it will.

Comment: I have added all the things you suggested but my app is not working as I want.There seems to some issue. I want only my one screen to be changed as per auto-rotation but here all of the screens are rotated and then not changing if I set it to landscape mode. .Also, if I try to change the screens in portrait mode. Screens still remain in the landscape mode. I have edited my code. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Hi @utkarsh you have forgotten to add 

SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations
  ([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    
on the 'initState()' method of _IframeScreenState class

Comment: @thusith.92 onwillpop is not working..dispose works just fine